# How to launch electron app using child_process in spectron testing

Tags: electron, child-process, spectron

Is it possible to launch electron app using command line with help of require('child_process') in spectron,

Normally we launch the app using command prompt like below,

> cd C:\Program Files\Project
>
> C:\Program Files\Project>Launcher.exe test.json

So we have to automate this in spectron testing, can you please someone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define that scripts into your `package.json` file as a script and you can define it to run with command line script when `npm` triggered. Npm will perform that commands.

For example script parameters in package.json, when you call `npm test` from terminal, your code execute firstly `locate-directory` script and after that will run `run-test` script:

```
"scripts": {
   "locate-directory": "cd C:\Program Files\Project"
   "run-test: "C:\Program Files\Project>Launcher.exe test.json"
   "test": "npm-run-all --serial locate-directory run-test"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Selcuk. I have one more doubt, if the app launch from here. how can I use the 'app' variable in Test. I have to do end to end testing electron using spectron.
Note:- I'm referring the URL https://www.wintellect.com/end-end-testing-electron-apps-spectron/

Comment: You can define app variable in your before hooks.

Comment: How can I define app variable after the app launched from scripts which you mentioned above. Because they launched the app using below code
var app = new Application({
            path: electronPath,
            args: [appPath]
        });
But in our case, we have launched the app from scripts in package.json